# Geometric mean of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, radicals, positive-definite

**Edited:**

I will give some definitions.

> **Definition 1** A matrix $C$ is called the square root of matrix $A$ if it satisfies $C^2=A$. It can be written as $C=A^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
>
> **Definition 2** Given two positive definite matrices $A,B$. The geometric mean of $A$ and $B$ is defined as
>   $$A\#B=A^{\frac{1}{2}}(A^{-\frac{1}{2}}BA^{-\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

I want to proof that $A\#B$ is the only positive definite solution of the equation
$$XA^{-1}X=B.$$
First, I must proof that $A\#B$ is the solution for the equation above. The proof is already given by Mr.@Tamshin Dion in the answer below. Next, I must proof that $A\#B$ is the only positive definite solution for the equation.

Let $X=A^{\frac{1}{2}}(A^{-\frac{1}{2}}BA^{-\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ satisfying
$$XA^{-1}X=B.$$
Let $Y$ is another positive definite matrix satisfying 
$$YA^{-1}Y=B.$$
Since $Y$ is positive definite, then it is also hermitian. By Spectral Theorem, there exist a unitary matrix $U$ such that
$$Y=UDU^*$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Then, we have
\begin{align*}
YA^{-1}Y=B &\iff (UDU^*)A^{-1}(UDU^*)=B\\
  &\iff
  DU^*A^{-1}UD=U^*BU\\
  &\iff
  (UD)^*A^{-1}UD=U^*BU\\
  &\iff
  (UD)^*A^{-1}UD=U^*XA^{-1}XU\\
  &\iff
  (UD)^*A^{-1}UD=(X^*U)^*A^{-1}(XU)\\
  &\iff
  (UD)^*A^{-1}UD=(XU)^*A^{-1}(XU)
\end{align*}
Now, Iam stuck in here. If I can show that $UD=XU$, then $UDU^*=X$ so that $Y=X$. But, how to proof it?

Notes :

1. For the definition of the geometric mean, I use Rajendra Bhatia's book "Positive Definite Matrices".
2. $U^*$ denotes conjugate transpose.

Comment: But $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not defined good.

Comment: If so, $A\#B=B.$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it.

Comment: Because $A^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{-\frac{1}{2}}=I.$ See please your definition.

Comment: I'm sorry. I guess the notation gives an ambiguation. I will edit it.

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing a square root on the inner term, i.e. $A\#B=A^{1/2}\left(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}\right)^{1/2}A^{1/2}$? // *Edit:* Indeed, the square root is there in eq. 2.9 of "[The Riemannian Mean of Positive Matrices](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~nielsen/MIGBOOKWEB/9783642302312-c2.pdf)" also by Bhatia.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the correction again.

Answer (score 1):

Since $XA^{-1}X=B$, we have $$\boxed{(A^{-\frac{1}{2}}XA^{-\frac{1}{2}})(A^{-\frac{1}{2}}XA^{-\frac{1}{2}})=A^{-\frac{1}{2}}BA^{-\frac{1}{2}}}$$
Then $X=A^{\frac{1}{2}}(A^{-\frac{1}{2}}BA^{-\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{\frac{1}{2}}.$

Comment: Is $X=A^{\frac{1}{2}}(A^{-\frac{1}{2}}BA^{-\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ **the only** positive definite solution for the equation $XA^{-1}X=B$?

Comment: I think I found something and I will edit my question again