# Matrix multiplication equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've already known that if $A=B$, then $AC=BC$. And the converse is not true. Is there any condition for the matrices $A$ and $B$ so that the converse is true?

Comment: No condition on $A$ and $B$ will make the converse true. Example: $C = 0$. The condition should be on $C$, e.g. $C$ is invertible.

Comment: So if $C$ is invertible, the converse is true?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You see it by multiplying on the right by $C^{-1}$.

Comment: Ahh yes thank you for the answer. If you please, do you know how to solve my problem in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3490784/715404 ? My question is motivated from it.

Answer (score 0):

For three matrices $~A,~ B~$ and $~C~$ of the same order, let $~AC=BC~$.

Which gives, $~ AC-BC=0\implies (A-B)C=0~\implies  A-B=0~~~\text{if$~~C\ne \mathbf{0}$}$.

i.e., if $~C~$ is invertible, then $~AC=BC\implies A=B~.$